# "ef migrations add" always recreates foreign keys in the new migration

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have RC1 with VS 2015 update 1 installed.

Whenever I try adding a new migration the same set of foreign keys get recreated in the Up method. Meaning they get dropped then directly added.

For example, when I add a migration without changing any of the models this gets generated (similar stuff is also generated in the Down method of course):

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityRoleClaim<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId", table: "AspNetRoleClaims");
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserClaim<string>_ApplicationUser_UserId", table: "AspNetUserClaims");
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserLogin<string>_ApplicationUser_UserId", table: "AspNetUserLogins");
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId", table: "AspNetUserRoles");
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_ApplicationUser_UserId", table: "AspNetUserRoles");
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "UserId",
        table: "AspNetUserLogins",
        nullable: false);
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "UserId",
        table: "AspNetUserClaims",
        nullable: false);
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "RoleId",
        table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
        nullable: false);
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_IdentityRoleClaim<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId",
        table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
        column: "RoleId",
        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_IdentityUserClaim<string>_ApplicationUser_UserId",
        table: "AspNetUserClaims",
        column: "UserId",
        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_IdentityUserLogin<string>_ApplicationUser_UserId",
        table: "AspNetUserLogins",
        column: "UserId",
        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId",
        table: "AspNetUserRoles",
        column: "RoleId",
        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_ApplicationUser_UserId",
        table: "AspNetUserRoles",
        column: "UserId",
        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}
```

This is completely useless, and it looks like it always happens in my case. I tried this in an aspnet5 application and also in a normal console app.

Comment: Known issue:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3751  Just remove the code generated from your Up and Down Method.

Comment: Oh, I searched but didn't find an open issue. It seems it's already fixed and the fix is coming for rc2. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and it has already been fixed, the fix is coming for rc2. The issue was tracked [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3751).

Thanks @firste.

Comment: is there a way to get this update? cause it's very irritating

Comment: I honestly don't know. After I spent a lot of time hitting huge limitations with EF Core (7) I finally switched to EF6 again at least until Core matures and I've never been happier in my life. EF Core is just not production quality right now.

Comment: RC2 is probably coming this month BTW.