# EF7 Code First keeps dropping and recreating foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm constantly being notified that 'There are pending model changes for ApplicationDbContext'. The migrations that are being generated appear only to drop a bunch of foreign keys and then recreate them. The following is an example of one where I've made no db changes but have had this message:

```
    public partial class MysteryMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityRoleClaim<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId", table: "AspNetRoleClaims");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserClaim<string>_User_UserId", table: "AspNetUserClaims");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserLogin<string>_User_UserId", table: "AspNetUserLogins");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId", table: "AspNetUserRoles");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_User_UserId", table: "AspNetUserRoles");
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityRoleClaim<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            column: "RoleId",
            principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserClaim<string>_User_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserClaims",
            column: "UserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserLogin<string>_User_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            column: "UserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "RoleId",
            principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_User_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "UserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityRoleClaim<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId", table: "AspNetRoleClaims");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserClaim<string>_User_UserId", table: "AspNetUserClaims");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserLogin<string>_User_UserId", table: "AspNetUserLogins");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId", table: "AspNetUserRoles");
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_User_UserId", table: "AspNetUserRoles");
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityRoleClaim<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            column: "RoleId",
            principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserClaim<string>_User_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserClaims",
            column: "UserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserLogin<string>_User_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            column: "UserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_IdentityRole_RoleId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "RoleId",
            principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_IdentityUserRole<string>_User_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            column: "UserId",
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }
}
```

These foreign keys are dropped + recreated even when I have a legit migration that I need to run. I'm using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` `3.0.0-rc1-final`.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening, and how I can put an end to it?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, as per usual the next thing I searched after posting this turned up the answer!

Duplicate question here: ["ef migrations add" always recreates foreign keys in the new migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082913/ef-migrations-add-always-recreates-foreign-keys-in-the-new-migration)

Basically it's an RC1 issue and will be fixed in the forthcoming RC2